# How to make cumulative sum still integer in pyspark

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

Here's my current output

```
+---+------------+
| ix|last_x_month|
+---+------------+
|  1|         1.0|
|  1|         2.0|
|  1|         3.0|
|  1|         4.0|
|  1|         5.0|
+---+------------+
```

Here's my code

```
import sys
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
df = df.withColumn('last_x_month', F.sum(datamonthly.ix).over(Window.partitionBy().orderBy().rowsBetween(-sys.maxsize, 0)))
```

Here's my expected output (still integer)

```
+---+------------+
| ix|last_x_month|
+---+------------+
|  1|           1|
|  1|           2|
|  1|           3|
|  1|           4|
|  1|           5|
+---+------------+
```

Note:
I also already try convert to Integer by using `datamonthly.withColumn("last_x_month",datamonthly.last_x_month.cast(IntegerType()))`

and still give similar output

Comment: `int(F.sum(datamonthly.ix))`?

Comment: `TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'Column'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cast is working fine -

## Data Preparation

```
input_list = [(1.0,),(1.0,),(1.0,),(1.0,),(1.0,)]

sparkDF = sql.createDataFrame(input_list, ['ix'])

sparkDF.show()

+---+
| ix|
+---+
|1.0|
|1.0|
|1.0|
|1.0|
|1.0|
+---+
```

## Window & Cast

```
window = Window.partitionBy().orderBy().rowsBetween(-sys.maxsize, 0)

sparkDF = sparkDF.withColumn('last_x_month', F.sum('ix').over(window))

to_convert = ['ix','last_x_month']

sparkDF = reduce(lambda df, x: df.withColumn(f'{x}_int',F.col(x).cast(IntegerType())), to_convert, sparkDF)

sparkDF.show()

+---+------------+------+----------------+
| ix|last_x_month|ix_int|last_x_month_int|
+---+------------+------+----------------+
|1.0|         1.0|     1|               1|
|1.0|         2.0|     1|               2|
|1.0|         3.0|     1|               3|
|1.0|         4.0|     1|               4|
|1.0|         5.0|     1|               5|
+---+------------+------+----------------+
```